# Table and its captions on different pages

Tags: tables, captions

I have a really long table that fits the whole page (in fact it's a really wide table that I have rotated by 90 degrees):

```
\begin{table}[!pht]
\caption{ ... some quite long description }
\begin{sideways}\begin{minipage}{0.9\textheight}\begin{center}\begin{small}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|cccccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
... a lot of data...
```

But the caption and table are overlapping. Is there a way to show on one page only the description, and on the another page only the table (but preserving the numeration of table environment)?

Comment: So, you want the table on one page, together with its label "Table 42", and then the text of the caption on another page?

Comment: nope, I want just the table on one page, and label "Table 5.6" on the bottom of earlier page with the description (and information: "table on next page")

Comment: I see. And both of these pages should have nothing else on them?

Comment: no, the page with the table should be empty - in fact nothing else would fit on it. But the page with the label and description can be a normal page - I just want the label/description at the bottom of it (it would get about 1/3 of the page)

Comment: But two empty pages is also an option, the description on left page, and the table on right page (I use twoside layout)

Comment: A possible strategy: have an empty table, with a label and caption, then follow it with your big table, without a label or caption. The only danger there is that the big table might not appear on the *very* next page. (But you might be lucky!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\ContinuedFloat` command from `caption` may be of use:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \listoftables%
    \clearpage%
    \lipsum%
    \begin{sidewaystable}[!p]
        \caption{A name for a full-page table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|cccccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \ContinuedFloat%
        \caption[]{{\lipsum[1]}}
        \hline%
    \end{table}
    \lipsum%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using this method I managed to get what I want. Thanks for the hint!